# React router v6 match multiple paths without rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In older version of react router I was able to do the following:

```js
<Switch>
   <Route path={["/search","/user/:userId"]}>
     <ResizeableWindows>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/search">
           <SearchPage/>
         </Route>
         <Route path="/user/:userId">
           <UserPage/>
         </Route>
       </Switch>
     </ResizeableWindows>
   </Route>
   <Route path="/about">
     <AboutPage/>
   </Route>
</Switch>
```

By doing it this way I could prevent the `<ResizeableWindows/>` component from being rerendered (meaning its state was not destroyed) when users navigate between the `<UserPage/>` and `<SearchPage/>`.

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish the same behavior in react router v6 since the `path` prop can no longer be an array.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do the following:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <ResizeableWindows>
        <Outlet />
      </ResizeableWindows>
    }
  >
    <Route path="search" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="user/:userId" element={<UserPage />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```